# Dynamically creating web page (using portion of URL as a variable)

Tags: url, dynamic

In a site I'm developing I have a page that presents a post based on the variable in the url:
`http://www.mywebsite.com?id=18`
So this would load the post who's ID is 18 in the mySQL database.

I would like the create the same effect, but with the url being something like:
`http://www.mywebsite.com/articles/title-of-article-18/`

Would there be a way to create these pages on the fly with dynamic post content, where the url would originally be created by:
`"http://www.mywebsite.com/articles/" + postTitle`

Comment: What is your underlying technology (platform/language, server, etc.)? Every environment has its own way of achieving this, so the answer is "yes", but you have to give more information to get specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for mod_rewrite and rewriting of urls via htaccess.

What it does is it takes patterns from your url, and the htaccess file detects the pattern redirects that to http://www.mywebsite.com?id=18. Users still see the nice url.

The  directory /articles/title-of-article-18/ will not actually exist, and the user never really reaches that location because the htaccess secretly changes the url that the server processes.

See 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

or a random tutorial I found:
http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 0):

try url-rewriting

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/